# JQuery if statement with negative & positive values

Tags: jquery, if-statement, numbers

I got two variables in a function: $x= -660px and is fixed and $y which is reduced by 20px each time the function is called. $y = 220px the first time the function is called. 
In the function I got an if else statement

```
    if($y > $x){
    //do something
    }else{
    //do nothing
    }
```

What I'm trying to get is for $y to be reduced as long as its bigger than -660px and then stop.

it works fine until $y = -20px. ie. the if statement 'does something' until $y = -20px and then it stops but doesn't execute the 'else' statement.

I can't find out what's wrong with it. Is this correct or might my problem  come from somewhere else?

---

Comment: You'll need to post more of your code. The code you *have* posted would not demonstrate this problem. In order to give people the best possible chance of assisting you, I strongly recommend you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: it has to execute, can you post more code to see if the problem is something else

Comment: are you comparing strings with `px` in them or numbers? Show more code  and create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: Does `$x` actually equal `-660px` or is it `-660`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `if($y < $x)` since they are negative values?

This works:

```
$(function(){
    var x=0,y=-660;
    var inter = setInterval(function(){
        if(y < x)
            subtract();
        else
            clearInterval(inter);
    },200);
    function subtract(){
        x = x-20;
        $('body').append('<br />x='+x+' y='+y);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x3sDw/)

Working with px values:

```
$(function(){
    var x="0px",y="-660px";
    var inter = setInterval(function(){
        if(parseInt(y) < parseInt(x))
            subtract();
        else
            clearInterval(inter);
    },200);
    function subtract(){
        x = (parseInt(x)-20)+"px";
        $('body').append('<br />x='+x+' y='+y);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x3sDw/1/)